# Excel not well formated in JasperReports

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, format

When i export my report to Excel, my cells don't display the whole text if there is more than one row to be displayed in it; it just cuts a part of it and i need to expand the row manually to see the all the data in it

I use the following formatting:

```
<band height="21">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="pageHeader" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="6" width="88" height="15"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Cambria" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[First Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
</band>

 <band height="30" splitType="Prevent">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="88" height="25"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Cambria" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{firstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
</band>
```

Is there a xls property i should set?

Comment: What version of JR are you using? Can you post the screenshot of your report's design (in *iReport*)?

Comment: I've always had this same problem but just assumed the user needed to format the Excel to their liking. Will be interested to see if you get a better answer.

Comment: Are you using [JRXlsExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRXlsExporter.html) or [JRXlsxExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/ooxml/JRXlsxExporter.html)? Maybe swap and see if it makes a difference?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem setting line spacing to double at text field properties menu.

Dosn't look different but shows full text.

Comment: I tried Line Spacing "1_1_2" and it looks alright. It seems like Excel uses this line spacing by default, but jasper calculates with "Single".